# Google App Engine (GAE) - do instances use a shared disk?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine (GAE) and my `app.yaml` looks like this:

```
runtime: custom # uses Dockerfile
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 2
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 12
  disk_size_gb: 50
```

The 50GB disk, is it shared between instances? The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/reference/app-yaml#resource-settings) are silent on this issue. I'm downloading files to the disk and each instance will need to be able to access the files I am downloading.

If the disk is not shared, how can I share files between instances?

I know I could download them from Google Cloud storage on demand, but these are video files and instant access is needed for every instance. Downloading the video files on demand would be too slow.

### Optional Reading

The reason instant access is needed is because I am using `ffmpeg` to produce a photo from the video at frame X (or time X). When a photo of the video is taken, these photos need to be made available to the user as quickly as possible.

Comment: GAE Flex does not share disk space between instances. Filestore which is an NFS can work, the problem is that you cannot mount the NFS at execution in Flex so this should be made manually which is a problem when the app scales or the instances are recreated. Possibly you may want to go with GKE or a MIG in GCE. Maybe someone else can share any ideas

Comment: thanks, a very useful insight ... you mention GAE flex a lot, do the same issues apply to GAE standard?

Comment: Yes, this applies for GAE standard too. In fact GAE standard does not support something like a disk, instead the files can be "stored" in memory in `/tmp` so the storage depends on the memory available for the instance type you choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 50 Gb disk in your GAE, be it standard or flex, there is no way you can share instances between GAE, as the storage is dedicated.
You tried GCS, since video file processing is involved and GCS is object based storage.
So the alternative to this could be  Filestore but it is not yet supported for GAE Flex despite the possibility of SSH into its underlying fully-managed machine.

There is a way if you use the `/tmp`  folder. However, it will store files in the RAM of the instance, so note that it will take up memory and that it is temporary (as the folder's name suggests).

For more details, see the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-temp-files) or [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#filesystem).